# Оператор try/catch

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Есть программа(клиент/сервер), который даёт возможность брать данные из БД mssql.

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
     OnCallAlgorithm();
 }

 //метод

 static void OnCallAlgorithm() {

     ConsoleApplication1.CallAlgorithm.ForSendingSoapClient client = new CallAlgorithm.ForSendingSoapClient();
     SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
     connect.ConnectionString = @ "Data Source=Пример-ПК;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;Integrated Security=True";


     connect.Open();
     string data = string.Format(@ "select metaAlg,datetime from Alg_stack");
     SqlDataAdapter algorithm_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(data, connect);
     DataTable algorithm_table = new DataTable();
     algorithm_adapter.Fill(algorithm_table);
     foreach(DataRow algorithm_row in algorithm_table.Rows) {
         try {
             string algorithm_name = algorithm_row["metaAlg"].ToString();
             string algorithm_date = algorithm_row["datetime"].ToString();


             client.CallAlgorithmByDate(algorithm_name, algorithm_date);
         } catch (Exception e) {


         }
     }
     connect.Close();


     string sql_data = "select * from Alg_stack";
     SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_data, connect);
     DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
     data_adapter.Fill(data_table);
     foreach(DataRow data_row in data_table.Rows) {
         string sql = "UPDATE Alg_stack SET st=1 WHERE st = 0 ";
         connect.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connect.Close();


         string data_status = data_row["st"].ToString();
         switch (data_status) {
             case "1":
                 {

                     //Если успешно отправлены данные то записать в              
                     //comment "успешно"
                     string succesful = "update Alg_stack set comment ='Успешно'  where comment is null";
                     connect.Open();
                     SqlCommand cmd_2 = new SqlCommand(succesful, connect);
                     cmd_2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     connect.Close();
                 }
                 break;

             case "2":
                 {
                     string sql_error = "Ошибка";
                     string error = string.Format(@ "update Alg_stack set comment = {} where comment is null", sql_error);
                     connect.Open();
                     SqlCommand cmd_3 = new SqlCommand(error, connect);
                     cmd_3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     connect.Close();
                 }
                 break;

             case "3":
                 {
                     string sql_not_available = "Сервис не доступен";
                     string not_available = string.Format(@ "update Alg_stack set comment = {} where comment is null", sql_not_available);
                     connect.Open();
                     SqlCommand cmd_4 = new SqlCommand(not_available, connect);
                     cmd_4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     connect.Close();
                 }
                 break;

         }
     }
 }
```

Сервер берёт данные от клиента, если успешно то в колонку "comment" напишет "успешно"(это сделано). Теперь, нужно создать исключение (с помощью try/catch) добавить в "comment". 
Исключении:

> Тайм-аут канала запроса во время ожидания  истёк.  Увеличьте значение
>   времени тайм-аута, передаваемое вызову при Request или увеличьте
>   значение SendTimeout

и ещё, если неправильно поставил адрес сервера

> Прослушивание на http://192.168.1.5/services/forsending.asmx не
>   выполняла ни одна конечная точка, которая могла бы принять сообщение.
>   Среди прочих причин это могло быть вызвано неправильным адресом или
>   действием SOAP

Буду очень благодарен!

Нашёл кое-что, что написать в условии `if`

```
 if () {
     throw new Exception(@ "Тайм-аут канала запроса во время ожидания истёк.Увеличьте значение времени тайм-аута, передаваемое вызову при 
         Request или увеличьте значение SendTimeout ");
     }
```

Comment: Не понятно, где вы в приведённом коде хотите выбросить исключение. Возможно вы всё-таки хотите поймать исключение выбрасываемое client.CallAlgorithmByDate ? Тогда, возможно вам поможет свойство исключения Message, в котором содержится текст исключения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например: раз вы хотите *оповещать* пользователя о неудачном соединении то тогда необходимо обернуть в `try` метод `connect.Open();` который открывает соединения с сервером, аналогично поступаем с прочими методами.

---

```
try
{
    connect.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //здесь обрабатываем исключение
}
```

блоков `catch` может быть несколько, в этом случае код мог бы выглядеть как то так:

```
try
{
    //например здесь какая то проверка на правильность аргументов
    if(arg==null)
        throw new Exception();
    connect.Open();
}
catch (ArgumentNullException e)
{
    //здесь обрабатываем исключение
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
   //здесь обрабатываем исключение
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //здесь обрабатываем исключение
}
```

т.е. в данном случае мы отлавливаем *конкретные* исключения: `InvalidOperationException`, `ArgumentNullException`, но так же мы сможет обработать *непредвиденное* исключение `Exception`

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `try/catch` ловят исключения, а создают с помощью ключевого слова `throw`, например:

```
throw new Exception("Тайм-аут канала запроса во время ожидания  истёк.
   Увеличьте значение времени тайм-аута, передаваемое вызову при 
   Request или увеличьте значение SendTimeout");
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос