# Как отследить ошибки или проблемы при отправке пост запроса?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Я отправляю пост запрос и десереализую пришедший ответ таким образом:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ссылка.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "http://ссылка.php" + "&id=" + id;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response1 = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response1.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MyJson p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(responseFromServer);
```

Как можно отследить ошибки минуя вылет приложения. Например пропал интернет или пришел не правильный json?

Comment: в try ... catch завернуть не пробовали?

Comment: @rdorn пойду гуглить как завернуть в них :-D

Comment: тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544672/198316 хороший пример использования с небольшими пояснениями. Ну и в MSDN почитайте https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: вообще исключения и их обработка, это как бы основы языка, без них вам очень тяжко будет, наверстывайте пока не поздно.